# Regex not working for RedirectMatch

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have the following URL on my site that inadvertently got indexed while doing some site testing. I am trying to redirect the URLs to the correct page on my site. For whatever reason I can't get the redirect to actually work as intended.

Here is the URL indexed on my site

`domain.com/wa/-county/communityname`

Sometimes a community is actually a city and needs to be redirected. The URL should actually be redirected to:

`domain.com/wa/cityname`

For those instances where a community is actually a city.

Now here is the the part that is throwing a wrench in my works I believe.

`/-county/` needs to explicitly match that text. I do have some URL instances on the site where the structure is:

`domain.com/wa/king-county/selah`

The URLs are generated dynamically. The Itemid of the site is what causes the county name `king` in this case to be generated. The indexed URLs just got indexed without the county name portion of the URL.

Here is the regex and redirectmatch I have tried so far.

```
RedirectMatch 301 (\/-county\/)(.+$) /wa/$2
```

Now the way I understand this is

```
(.*$) = $2
```

Can anyone shed any additional light on this subject for me?

Here is a link to the [Regex101 Test](https://regex101.com/r/PPaMNr/1)

Comment: try this.. https://regex101.com/r/PPaMNr/3 `(\/[^\/]*?-county\/)(.+$)` and you are correct `$2` is the second group in the match which is `(.+$)`. First group $1 is everything matched by `(\/[^\/]*?-county\/)`

Comment: @bulbus I tried to implement the code you posted on regex101. The RedirectMatch never catches the url and redirects. The Regex itself does look good however.

Comment: got it! that you need to capture more groups see my other comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule as your very first rule site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([\w-]+)/-county/(.+)$ /$1/$2
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache when testing this change.

Comment: I added this line immediately after RewriteEngine On and it did nothing. Tested in 3 separate browsers.

Comment: he wants to make sure `http://example.com/wa/king-county/selah` is turned to `http://example.com/wa/selah`

Comment: he wants to make sure `http://example.com/wa/king-castle-county/selah` is turned to `http://example.com/wa/selah` or so I think.

Comment: @bulbus is correct. I want to turn http://example.com/wa/-county/selah into http://example.com/wa/selah. The reason is because the county "king" is missing in the url. This second regex did not work either. I am testing with domain.com/wa/-county/crane which should become domain.com/crane

Comment: ([\w-]+)\/-county\/(.+)$ gives me "wa" and "crane". But the RedirectMatch isn't redirecting.

Comment: @anubhava `^/` at the beginning of the line??

Comment: Here is the line as I have it now
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([\w-]+)\/-county\/(.+)$ /$1/$2

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/sKMnjd/2 with `RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)\/[^\/]*-county\/(.+)$ /$1/$2` will make `http://example.com/wa/king-county/selah`, `http://example.com/wa/-county/selah`, `http://example.com/wa/king-castle-county/selah` to `http://example.com/wa/selah`

Comment: 1. regex101 is not a tester website for rewrite rules. 2. Please only test the rules I provide. 3. `.*` will of course match anything.

Comment: My htaccess file had for some reason stopped redirecting all together. I have added your regex rule to a new htaccess file and it appears to be working satisfactorily. Thanks for the help @anubhava.